# FileNotFoundError: while executing some cli command in -- odoo 14

Tags: command-line-interface, odoo, odoo-14

I installed v14 second time and this is running fine. But i found couple of problems like some of the cli command fails to execute.
Like

```
./odoo-bin shall -d dev 

./odoo-bin scafolled local-payment mymodules

./odoo-bin populate
```

etc ....

Error is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/rezaulhasan/Computer/Dev/odoo/odoo/customaddons'
```

clue is my previous version i created my custom module folder in this `/Users/rezaulhasan/Computer/Dev/odoo/odoo/customaddons` location.

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You previously added that location in the `addons_path` configuration of odoo configuration file (`.conf`). Probably that directory location doesn't exists any more, there are two ways you can solve this. Either create just a empty directory with `mkdir -p /Users/rezaulhasan/Computer/Dev/odoo/odoo/customaddons`, or just remove the addons_path `/Users/rezaulhasan/Computer/Dev/odoo/odoo/customaddons` from your current odoo conf file.

Comment: creating empty folder is a solution but i am not recommending it. i do not run odoo-bin with any config file. moreover in config file there is no configuration like this.

Comment: even if you are not running `odoo-bin` with `-c` or `--conf`, odoo itself generates a `conf` file automatically under `.local` directory. if you are talking about recommended setup, trust me running Odoo service without `-c` or `--conf` is not recommended by any means.